# Probability of choosing the same number

Tags: probability

Assume $n$ people choose a number between $1$ and $k$ uniformly at random, simultaneously. What is the probability that any two of the $n$ people get the same number?

I tried: The probability that two people choose the same number is $\frac1k$. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ different pairs. How to proceed from this?

Thanks.

Comment: Archi duplicate.

Comment: You can search for birthday on this site, and see [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) in Wikipedia

Answer (score 12):

There are $k$ choices and $n$ people.

- First person will choose a random number.
- Second person will choose a random number and will have $1\over k$ probability to choose the number chosen by others.
- Third person will have $2\over k$ probability.
- $n$-th person will have ${n-1} \over k$ probability.

Geting the probability that way will be way too hard, let's get the probability of *not* having two identical choices:

- First person will choose a random number (and have $k \over k$ probability).
- Second person will choose a random number and have $k-1 \over k$ to choose the number not chosen by others.
- Third person will have $k-2 \over k$ probability.
- $n$-th person will have $k-n+1 \over k$ probability.

Probability ($p$) is then:
$$
p=1-{{k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)...(k-n+3)(k-n+2)(k-n+1)} \over {k^n}}=1-{k! \over {k^n(k-n)! }}
$$

Comment: What about n > k?

Comment: if n>k the probability that everyone picks something unique is 0

Answer (score 2):

Hint: find the probability that all the numbers are distinct.