# Probability of at least X same choices by N people choosing out of a set of Y options

Tags: probability-theory

I am currently facing the following problem:

There is a set of integers from 1 to Y, and N people choosing a random number of this set. What is then the probability that there is at least one number which is chosen at least X times?

For X = 2 (so in other words, there is no double occupancy at all), I know this problem can be solved using

$P = 1 - \frac{k!}{k^n (k-n)!}$,

as explained in the answer to this question:
[Probability of choosing the same number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509679/probability-of-choosing-the-same-number)

However, I am unable to come up with a solution to the more general form as in my question. Can anyone think of a general method of determining this probability?