# Matching appointment problem

Tags: probability

I have N people trying to find a common day for appointment in a period of D days.
Each person chooses F favorite days in which he's available during that period.

What is the probability that they will find a matching day for everybody, as function of N,D and F?

A trivial example would be N=2 persons choosing F=1 favorite day over D=7 days.
The probability will be P(2,7,1)=1/7.

How to generalize this formula? I'm having trouble combining probabilities I think.

Also, I don't know if this problem can be reframed into a common mathematical problem

P.S. as I'm writing this I'm trying to understand if this is the same problem expressed here

[Probability of N people choosing at least one of the same number when simultaneously choosing a set of X distinct numbers from a set of K numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211964/probability-of-n-people-choosing-at-least-one-of-the-same-number-when-simultaneo)

Comment: If everybody chooses his days uniformly at random from the list of available days, and the choices of the various people are independent, then yes, they are the same question.

Comment: however, the answer makes an assumption that I don't understand, in my case it will be D-N*F>=0, which doesn't make sense

Comment: I'm sorry.  I misread the other question.  It is different.  You'll have to use the [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to answer your question.

Comment: This is easy enough if there are just two people.  The conceptual jump comes at $3$ people.  Try doing it when $3$ people each choose $2$ days from $n$.  What if they each choose $3$ days?  Once you can answer the general question for $3$ people, you'll be able to answer it for any number.