# Probability of three digits being the same

Tags: probability, random

I have four people (n) and every time each is getting a random three digit combination (000-999). This means there are 1000 possible combinations (k).

I want to know how probable it is for two or more people to get the same three digits in idk let's say 10,000 trys.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/765985/633161) but I calculated it with n=4 and k=1000 and it doesn't seem to be the right formula for my use case. How would I calculate something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is
$$
p=1-\left[\frac{(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{k^3}\right]^N,
$$
where $N$ is the number of trials.

Comment: In 100 games there is a 50% chance? That's a lot!

Comment: Yes, according to calculation it is about 45%.